# 2 custom posts types, in their own columns, one pagination for both

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, loop, pagination

I have a page template has 2 columns. 
Each column has a loop for a single custom post type, with pagination.

The pagination links work for both columns, when you click any number it will take you to the page# for BOTH post types (there's a "sorry no more posts" message if one post type runs out of posts)

I want to maintain this functionality, but combine the pagination into only 1 section that checks the total number of posts for BOTH post types and creates the links based on that number, rather than having 2 separate link lists below each column.

How can I combine the pagination from these 2 loops OR combine the master loop but still break the posts into 2 columns, by post type?

I have already tried a few things

1. 1 loop, 2 post types (do not know how to break this into 2 columns) http://pastebin.com/JyDgW0J3
2. 2 loops, 2 columns, 2 paginations  http://pastebin.com/k4Kp9t9s

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

re 2. two loops, one pagination link:
remove the individual paginations;
add this at the end:

```
$max = max($ideas_query->max_num_pages,$opinions_query->max_num_pages);
if (function_exists('custom_pagination')) {
    custom_pagination($max,"",$paged);
}
```